# What am I missing? Chaining promises in jQuery and Dojo

Tags: jquery, dojo, jquery-deferred, deferred

The following code does not work the way I predicted:

```
jQuery.get("/api/resource/1")
      .then(function(res){ return res.length; })
      .then(function(res){ var length = res; });
```

I thought `length` would get the value of the returned length property from the function above, but it does not. The value of res will not be chained. But if I write this code in dojo, it will work as I predicted:

```
dojo.xhrGet({url:"/api/resource/1"})
    .then(function(res){ return res.length; })
    .then(function(res){ var length = res; });
```

What shall I do to make jQuery work the way I want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [deferred.pipe](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/).

Comment: Thanks! The pipe function works fine in newer versions of jQuery. Unfortunately I'm stuck with jQuery 1.5.2 (it's a Drupal site). Even if it works, I can not understand why JQuery is implemented this way. I think it is confusing. If I want to use the same value, I return the same value, right?

Answer (score 0):

It's because jQuery's deferred's 'then' method returns itself. Namely you added two handlers into the same deferred object. 
But dojo's deferred's 'then' method returns new one for deferred's chaining. 
It seems to be caused by the jQuery API's style as you know -  [Method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). Almost all jQuery's APIs return itself for method chaining pattern.

```
    var def1 = ​$.get("/echo/json").then(function(res) { console.dir(res); 
                      return res; });
    var def2 = def1.then(function(res) { console.dir(res);
                                 return res; });
    ​​​​​​​​if (def1 === def2) {
        console.log(">>> same deferred object.");
    } else {
        console.log(">>> different deferred object.");    
    }
```